# JQuery Ajax POST 500 Interval error

Tags: ajax

I have an error 500 (Internal Server Error), I dont know what is the problem 
m.ajaxTransport.a.send  @   jquery.min.js:4

(anonymous function)    @   add:198

fichier javascript:

```
$("#addItem").on('click',function(e){
e.preventDefault();
var id_produit = parseInt($("#produit_id option:selected").val());
        var prix = parseFloat($('#prix_produit').val());
        var remise = parseFloat($('#remise_produit').val());
        var qte = parseInt($('#count_produit').val());
        var id_facture = <?php echo($count_id); ?>;
        var data = [];
        data = {
            FacturesProduit: {
                facture_id : id_facture,
                produit_id : id_produit,
                prix : prix,
                remise : remise,
                quatite : qte
            }
            };
            console.log(data);
       var url = <?php echo $this->Html->url(array('controller' => 'facturesproduits' , 'action' => 'ajout_produit')); ?>;
        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            type: "POST",
            data: data,
            success: function (result) {
             console.log(result);
             }
});
});
```

Action :

```
public function ajout_produit() {
          $message = 'error';
        if ($this->request->is('ajax')) {
            $data = $this->request->data;
            if ($this->FacturesProduit->save($data)) {
                $message = 'success';
            }
        }
        echo json_encode($message);
        die();
    }
```

thanks

Comment: Have you checked error logs? Both framework and apache or whatever you use for server? What does the error say?

Comment: Does `$this->Html->url` return a valid URL and do you need to enclose the `url` with quotes ? Are you allowed to do a POST request on the returned URL?  Do you have access to the error logs ?

Comment: dans le logs error il ma dit                                            m.ajaxTransport.a.send @ jquery.min.js:4
m.extend.ajax @ jquery.min.js:4
(anonymous function) @ add:194
m.event.dispatch @ jquery.min.js:3
m.event.add.r.handle @ jquery.min.js:3